# Why is the potential energy for a body raised up by a height negative?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy

I tried deriving the potential energy of a body when raised at a height $h$ above the earths surface, using the formula:

$$PE = -W_\text{conservative}$$

where $W_\text{conservative}$ is the work done by conservative forces. I'm getting $-mgh$ for a body raised a height $h$ above the earths surface. Why is this negative?

Comment: Could you maybe include your method for deriving that formula? There are many places you could have accidentally gained or lost a - sign so its quite hard to tell what the problem is without seeing your maths.

Comment: I am guessing he probably did this and arrived at the -mgh term. F=-mg downwards and dx= +h and F.dx = -mgh and probably forgot about the -ve sign in the equation of PE. anyway its not potential energy but "change in potential energy" isnt that right ?

Answer (score 1):

Remember the definition of work: $\vec F.d\vec x=Fx\cos\theta$. In your case $\theta=180^o$, thus $\cos\theta=-1$. That is the minus sign you were missing.

Answer (score 0):

In your formula you don't calculate the potential energy, but the **difference** between the potential energy of the body at the lower level $P_E(h_0)$, and that at the higher level $P_E(h_1)$. Indeed, since $P_E(h_0) < P_E(h_1)$ you get $P_E(h_0) - P_E(h_1) < 0$ as expected.

Phenomenologically, starting from $h_0$, you have to invest some work to raise the object at the level $h_1$, s.t. $$P_E(h_0) + Work = P_E(h_1),$$
s.t. $$P_E(h_0) - P_E(h_1) = -Work.$$
Your mistake is that **not the field forces** do here the work for raising the body, but **you** do the work. So, for raising the object, you do work for adding to it potential energy.